# Why I cannot assign image to custom collect CollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I designed a custom `UICollectionViewCell` and added image view as an outlet. Then, I connected that image view with the cell. Somehow, I cannot assign image `(UIImage)` to that image view. Below is my code for `cellForItemAtIndexPath`.

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Service Gallary is my custom collection view cell.
    [self.collectionView registerClass:[ServiceGallaryCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:collectionCellIdentifier];

    ServiceGallaryCell *serviceCollectionCell = (ServiceGallaryCell*)[collectionView  dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:collectionCellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (collectionView == self.collectionView)
    {
        serviceCollectionCell.image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:_imagesArray[indexPath.row]];
    }

    return serviceCollectionCell; 
}
```

Comment: `[UIImage imageNamed:_imagesArray[indexPath.row]` is nil? What's exactly in `[UIImage imageNamed:_imagesArray[indexPath.row]`?

Comment: I am using Collection View in storyboard, not collection view controller.

Comment: No, it is not nil. These are names of images in Assets.

Comment: Use view debugger to see if the frame of the image view is as you intended it be.

Comment: I am embedding Collection View in UIViewController but I think it has nothing to do with assigning images. @interface ServiceGallery : UIViewController <UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource>

Comment: Do you enter the `if` statement? You may want to `registerClass: forCellWithReuseIdentifier:` before entering `collectionView: cellForItemAtIndexPath:` (too avoid too many calls). Is `serviceCollectionCell` nil?

Comment: No if statement but it is registering class.

Comment: if (collectionView == self.collectionView)? Why do you using it at all? And remember that you are comparing objects here using "=="

Comment: Nom serviceCollectionCell is not nill.

Comment: CollectionView is my UICollectionView IBOutlet. As, I am using viewcontroller, so I attached this outlet to view controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

   static NSString *CollectionViewIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";
   ServiceGallaryCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:CollectionViewIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

   cell.imageView.image = _imagesArray[indexPath.row];

   return serviceCollectionCell; 
}
```

Comment: I tried this also, but I think the error is related to UIViewController. Instead of using UIViewController, I must use UICollectionView Controller.

Comment: Yes, you must use  UICollectionViewController. And connect dataSource and delegate.

Comment: And register you class pass to viewDidLoad.

Comment: Okay, I am checking it.

Comment: How to register class in ViewDidLoad?

Comment: The same as: [self.collectionView registerClass:[ServiceGallaryCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:collectionCellIdentifier];

Comment: Same issue with UICollectionView Controller

Comment: Show me your array images.

Comment: I debugged whole code, somehow it was hiding imageView Cell. I do not know why. Image Array is correct.

Comment: Try replace your cell on standard cell: UICollectionViewCell  *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:CollectionViewIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath]

Comment: Yes, I replaced and it is now loading images but still very much strange behaviour. If you have less imageView Cells just to fit in screen, images are not loading and if you make Cell bigger, they start loading.

Comment: Now you can try to add imageView but on cell which is UICollectionViewController and so on to try. xib that you have created, you can delete.

Comment: when using UICollectionViewController class, there is no need to register a class. This also throws an error or warning to user. I removed that line and everything now works fine. Also, load the data for collectionView in viewWillAppear, not in viewDidLoad, otherwise you will see delay in loading elements.

Answer (score 0):

plz try this code

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {

   static NSString *CollectionViewIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";
   ServiceGallaryCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:CollectionViewIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

  [cell.image2 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:_imagesArray[indexPath.row]]]

  return serviceCollectionCell; 
}
```

Comment: Please, put your project on github for observing this case.